# flutter flame camera shake deprecated

Tags: flutter, camera, deprecated, shake, flame

[image]

When I tried to repeat some lecture of flutter flame, most of youtube instructors teach me this way to shake screen.
But IDE complaint using camera property directly was deprecated.

So,
What is best way to shake camera (or viewport or world) now days?

### try

- camera.shake(); // deprecated
- gameRef.camera.shake(); // deprecated
- gameRef.world.shake(); // method not exists
- gameRef.cameraComponent.shake(); // method not exists
- gameRef.cameraComponent.viewport.shake(); // method not exists
- gameRef.cameraComponent.camera.shake(); // method not exists

### expect

- no deprecated

Comment: Have you read the documentation that explains what to do instead? https://pub.dev/documentation/flame/latest/game/FlameGame/camera.html

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, manual said, do not use flameGame.camera directly, make cameraComponent and use that, so I did. But cameraComponent doesn't have shake method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shaking of the camera has become an effect instead of a method directly on the camera, this is how you can use it with the `CameraComponent`:

```dart
        cameraComponent.viewfinder.add(
          MoveEffect.by(
            Vector2(5, 5),
            PerlinNoiseEffectController(duration: 0.2, frequency: 400),
          ),
        );
```

And of course change the parameters to your liking.

Remember to import `flame_noise`, since that EffectController resides in there:
https://pub.dev/packages/flame_noise

Comment: - viewfinder can be replaced by viewport,
- Vector2 value -> shaking amount. Vector2.zero() will not move, Vector(30, 30) will  crazily shake camera.