Flutter Flame camera shake effect not working
I am working on a side shooter with Flame, and would like the screen to shake when the player is hit by a bullet.
I have found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698880/1843141
I implemented it as follows but that's not working:
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await Flame.device.fullScreen();
    await Flame.device.setLandscape();

    ...
    
    camera = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
      world: world,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
    );
    add(camera);
    
    ...
  }

  // I call this when the player's sprite detects a collision
  void shakeScreen() {
    camera.viewfinder.add(
      MoveEffect.by(
        Vector2(30, 30),
        NoiseEffectController(
          duration: 0.2,
          noise: PerlinNoise(frequency: 40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  ...
}

When I use the same method on a sprite, it shakes ¯\(ツ)/¯

Maybe it only works on sprites?

In the mentioned post, the creator of the library states that this should work. That said, maybe that's deprecated

Is there a background image?  Could you try it on that?

Good idea! That would be a nice workaround

I hope it works!  Always think outside the box when you hit a limitation and you might find a solution :0

Interesting this is a regression, this example uses that logic and I can see that it isn't working in there: https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Collision_Detection_Raycasting_Max_Distance
I'll have a closer look.

@malrok44 which platforms doesn't it work on for you? It doesn't seem to work on firefox for me, but it works on chromium (and other platforms), which is veeeery strange.

I am working on Windows 11 if that makes a difference. I have tested on Windows, Android and Edge, that worked on none of these targets.

I have just tested on my work's macbook (Chrome and desktop), and that did not work either  Maybe I'm not doing it properly?

@malrok44 you don't see anything on chrome if you have a higher duration and frequency either? Like 1 second and 400 in frequency.

I opened the issue here: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/3193

Thanks, I could have done it myself
